# Sequence of numbers based on start and end value of 2 cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a number range in two cell (Q7 start) and (S7 end). I am needing help in creating a formula  or macros to auto populate the sequence of the numbers inputted in columns D13:S16.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[Sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RUev.jpg)
[Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQfUb.png)

Comment: Can you add some sample data or a screenshot to your question?

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these formulas

D13: `=Q7`

E13: `=IFERROR(IF(D13+1>$S$7,"",D13+1),"")`

Then copy E13 to the right as far as you need.

[image]

Comment: Great this helped! Thank you very much.